# How much bandwidth does my server require?

Tags: web-hosting, hosting

I have blog + website hosted on Godaddy server. I get somewhere around 50k hits a day. I was thinking of hosting it on my own. I want to know whether a 2mbps connection is sufficient or not?
Somebody with self-hosting experience please guide...

Comment: It depends on the size of your Web site, what those hits do, et cetera.  You have to figure this out yourself.

Comment: How spread out are those 50k hits spread throughout the day?  80% in a two hour period will be a much greater load than if the 50k hits are evenly distributed throughout 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to guess how much you need, so "How do I find out how much bandwidth...." is the question you need to be asking.

1. What you really need to know is how much you peak out at, as this is how much you need.  If you don't have a nice even flow of traffic, a burstable bandwidth model where you are billed on the 95th percentile might be most cost effective.
2. How much access to this server do you have?  Have you tried asking godaddy if they can give you bandwidth usage stats for your website?
3. If you have root access, I recommend you use tcpdump to dump all the traffic for a day to a file.  You can then graph a filter on that traffic dump with wireshark that would filter out any non website traffic.

Answer (score 0):

some questions to consider :
 is this a $$$ issue?
 how much downtime are you currently experiencing at godaddy?
 how important is uptime to you?
 is your 2mbps connection 2mpbs up/down or async?

i would say that you probably can't beat their pricing, which i assume is close to the bottom of that market.

i would also say that you are going to have a hard time with consistent uptime.  consumer circuits can be very good over time but also can be down for hours at a time with no explanation which can be frustrating if you need the site/service to be up.

my suggestion is to not self-host but i only make that recommendation knowing what it really takes ($$$$$, time, effort, crossed fingers) to get a decent level (4 nines) of uptime on internet sites.